# Finding out authentication method of web API (websocket) to login with my own script (I have the login data)

Tags: authentication, websocket, cryptography, reverse-engineering

My parents own a wallbox for charging a electric car. The wallbox is controllable with an app which uses an authenticated API. I already did a MITM attack to get that traffic. I also have the login data, as it is the wallbox of my parents and they agreed that I do this. (If you are interested: I try to automate that the car is always charging when there is enough power from the photovoltaic but at the same time the car should never run low if there is not enough sun.)

I want to write a small Python script which controls the wallbox, but the only problem is, that I don‘t know how the authentication works.

Is there any way to find that out, without decompiling the app (which I found hard because it apparently uses React Native with the Hermes engine from Facebook which can‘t be decompiled as nicely as other Android apps)?
Is it realistic to find the used authentication method by just looking at the example I show below?
Or is the only way to understand the authentication with the decompiled app? I pasted an example of what I sniffed below.

If there is an easy solution to my problem, I am happy to take that, but if you say that I should look more into these and that, then I am also good with that, as I am kinda stuck at the moment.

Thank you very much!

##### Two messages from the API

They come automatically after opening the websocket connection.

```json
{
   "type":"hello",
   "message":"Hello app",
   "serial":"3215XXXX",
   "devicetype":"deviceName",
   "manufacturer":"companyName",
   "protocol":2
}
```

The first token stays the same for multiple hours, even if you make multiple requests to the API.

```json
{
   "type":"authRequired",
   "token1":"0dtOJ1LkCrMgaz5ri8MZmgHBcXXXXXXX",
   "token2":"Ij10ETYSo2GJSVMJlDNzMGW9TXXXXXXX"
}
```

##### From the app

```json
{
   "type":"auth",
   "token3":"b4eb9e8baae62429c577216aaXXXXXXX",
   "hash":"cbc3d99391db59e59174ddb01073157581afb2ad1e392433c9107477eXXXXXXX"
}
```

##### Answer from the API

```json
{
   "type":"authSuccess",
   "message":"Successfully authenticated"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not super-realistic to assess the auth method from that data, however, you can get some idea.

There could be multiple reasons why the server provides two tokens (rather than just one), but I'm going to give a "best estimation" example scenario. The auth method is possibly something fairly similar to this. It's possible that one of the two tokens is authenticating the server to the client.
One of the two tokens the server provides is likely some sort of *challenge* for the client: it may be a hash of current time or day, or a hash of a client-specific identifier, or just some random data used to prevent replay attacks.
The client response to the server is probably some hashed or encrypted combination of one of the tokens from the server and the client secret (your password, or username:password, or username:password:productID or something like that.)
The hash may be a protection against replay attacks by hashing the current time along with the client secret info, or possibly an authentication sequence number along with client secret info.

So as you can probably tell there are many, many possibilities here. It's possible the whole protocol is custom designed by the charging station manufacturer.

You might try sniffing some data again, and within the first token timeframe try to replay what your client sent. It will most likely not auth you, but It's possible you'll be presented with some error information that is useful and can give you more clues about what's going on.

Otherwise, the disassembler is probably going to be the way to go, and may be tedious, but should give you a much clearer picture of the correct auth protocol.